# Why imagePickerController crashes when fetching photo from library but from camera works fine

Tags: ios, swift

ImagePickerController crashes every time when fetching a photo from the library and the warning will show like this.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000033a8280'
```

I am using UIImagePickerController
but when I'm fetching photo from the camera it works fine.

I have put this code in info.list

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app wants to take pictures.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app wants to use your photos.</string>
```

this is all of my code in my viewcontroller
I want to fetch a photo from library by using ImagePickerController I don't know why it's crash.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var shopIDNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bgAddImage: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var confirmImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tapOnImage()

        shopIDNumber.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        bgAddImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        doneButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25

    }

    @objc func tapToImageView(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.allowsEditing = true

        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
                pickerController.sourceType = .camera
                self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }else{
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Mistake", message: "Camera Not Work", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Okey", style: .default) { (action) in
                }
                alert.addAction(okAction)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }))
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Library", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

        if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage

        }else if let originalImage:UIImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
        }

        if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
            confirmImage.image = selectedImage
        }
        self.doneButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 182.0 / 255.0, blue: 79.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func tapOnImage() {
        let tapGestureToImageView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapToImageView(sender:)))
        tapGestureToImageView.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        confirmImage?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        confirmImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureToImageView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Most probably the issue is with following.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var confirmImage: UIImageView!
```

Check if your Interface Builder is properly hooked with this outlet. Looks like it's broken or hooked into an incorrect type.

You can verify if the issue is here by commenting out following line:

```
confirmImage.image = selectedImage
```

When you comment out above line if app doesn't crash, my original assumption is correct.

Comment: I have check all that you suggest and commenting out this line

`confirmImage.image = selectedImage`

but it still crash and not just this viewcontroller but other viewcontroller that use imagePickerController too

Comment: I create new project and use this code it's work fine but in my old project it doesn't work

Comment: I have found the problem is come from Appdelegate thank you guy